# Symfony security - skip guard

Tags: php, symfony, security

I am trying to create a hybrid api-token/form login security using Symfony's (2.8.24) guard mechanism.

My security.yml looks like this:

```
security:

    acl:
        connection: default

    providers:
        jwt:
            id: app.jwt_user_provider

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            pattern: ^/
            guard:
                entry_point: app.jwt_authenticator
                authenticators:
                    - app.jwt_authenticator
                    - app.authenticator.form_login
            provider: jwt

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/general/info, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

So I have a `main` firewall with two configured authenticators. The entry point is the `app.jwt_authenticator`, with a fallback to the `app.authenticator.form_login`.

I want it so that when no token is present, that the `app.jwt_authenticator` is skipped.

The `getCredentials()` method of the `app.jwt_authenticator` looks like this basically:

```
public function getCredentials(Request $request): ?string
{
    $tokenString = $request->headers->get('Authorization');
    if (!$tokenString) {
        $this->logger->warn('No authorization header');

        return null;
    }

    return $tokenString;
}
```

So if there is no `Authorization` header it returns `null`.

And according to Symfony's documentation:

> Get the authentication credentials from the request and return them as
>   any type (e.g. an associate array). If you return null, authentication
>   will be skipped.

So I would expect this authenticator to be skipped when there is no `Authorization` header, but unfortunately that is not the case.

Even though `getCredentials()` returns `null` (and I have verified that it does), the `start()` method gets called instead of skipping this authenticator and moving on to the next.

Is my configuration not correct? Am I misunderstanding the mechanism?
What do I need to do to implement this hybrid?

Comment: Do you use AbstractGuardAuthenticator?

https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html

Cuz when i retrun null it works perfectly, it skeeps.

Comment: @ArturYukhatov I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the trick was to change the entrypoint to `app.authenticator.form_login`